# Sidekiq -- Email.delay.sendMail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actionmailer, sidekiq

So, I have this code

```
class InvoiceNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  default from: 'from@email.com',
          return_path: 'any@email.com'


  def testEmail(recipient)
    @account = recipient

    mail(to: recipient).deliver
  end

end
```

running the command (from console)

```
InvoiceNotifier.sendMail('my@email.com')
```

works, though

```
InvoiceNotifier.delay.sendMail('my@email.com')
```

does not work, and it returns a string.

How do I debug this?  I look at redis and it has 3 keys, though none of them appear to have any values.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perform method is not required.  The problem was I wasn't doing

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

from command line to actually have an interface to interact with..
http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast is a great place to go to learn since I wasn't really looking at the front page of sidekiq to do their 'get started guide' and while it's on the front page to execute this command, I didn't notice it when I was diving in.